# Can transparency be applied differently for each item of ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to create a control that displays a simple chat message.

Up to 10 messages are displayed.
The most recent message is always added to the end of the `ListView`
The oldest message is at the top of the `ListView`.

I want to make old messages more and more obscured (`Opacity`).

Do you have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not supported out-of-the-box, but you can achieve this behavior easily for a *fixed amount of items* using a trick. Each `ItemsControl` has a built-in alternation mechanism that is usually used to change the style or appearance of rows depending on an alternation index.

In this case we make use of this functionality to get the index of a `ListViewItem` and set `Opacity`.

- Set the `AlternationCount` property to the *fixed size* of your collection.
- Add an item container style to set the `Opacity` of the `ListViewItem`.
- Add an `AlternationConverter` with the opacity for each item.
- Bind the attached property `AlternationIndex` using the converter.

This way, the `AlternationIndex` is used to apply the corresponding opacity value.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSource}"
          AlternationCount="10">
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Style.Resources>
            <AlternationConverter x:Key="AlternationIndexToOpacityConverter">
               <system:Double>0.1</system:Double>
               <system:Double>0.2</system:Double>
               <system:Double>0.3</system:Double>
               <system:Double>0.4</system:Double>
               <system:Double>0.5</system:Double>
               <system:Double>0.6</system:Double>
               <system:Double>0.7</system:Double>
               <system:Double>0.8</system:Double>
               <system:Double>0.9</system:Double>
               <system:Double>1.0</system:Double>
            </AlternationConverter>
         </Style.Resources>
         <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource AlternationIndexToOpacityConverter}}"/>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

The result for an arbitrary collection of `string` looks like this.

[image: ListView with ten items and ascending opacity.]

If you want to apply a more sophisticated algorithm to for the opacity, create a custom value converter.

```
public class AlternationIndexToOpacityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (values == null || values.Length != 2)
         return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

      if (!(values[0] is int alternationCount) || !(values[1] is int alternationIndex))
         return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

      var proportion = (double) alternationIndex / (alternationCount - 1);
      return 0.3 + proportion * 0.7;
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

In this case, you would also need to bind the `AlternationCount` property, to get the collection size.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSource}"
          AlternationCount="10">
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Style.Resources>
            <local:AlternationIndexToOpacityConverter x:Key="AlternationIndexToOpacityConverter"/>
         </Style.Resources>
         <Setter Property="Opacity">
            <Setter.Value>
               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AlternationIndexToOpacityConverter}">
                  <Binding Path="AlternationCount" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}"/>
                  <Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
               </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

The result looks similar, but in this case, the minimum opacity is `0.3`.

[image: ListView with ten items and ascending opacity starting from 0.3.]

Comment: Your ideas and samples helped me a lot. I haven't applied it yet, but I think it's definitely a feature I want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Already Answered, But I'll give another idea to achieve this with out behind code.

The idea is just put a opacity gradient grid over `ListView`. from top to end, It blurry from the top of `Listview` and then clear at the bottom of `ListView`.   Make sure set `IsHitTestVisible` false, and change color of brush to background of `ListView`. and also Margin for `ScrollBar` Region.

I tested It, It works. but the quality is so-so. because Select Item highlight color also gets opacity, and grid overlay could cover scrollbar region.

But for who want easy way, I'll leave this comment. It would be easy way if your application don't need `ScrollBar`.

```xml
<Grid IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0 0 18 0">
  <Grid.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
      <GradientStop Color="#bbffffff" Offset="0.1"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#77ffffff" Offset="0.3"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#00ffffff" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```